# Which contact's phone number called me?

Tags: iphone, contacts

When a contact in my iPhone has multiple phone numbers how do I determine which number that person called me from? Short of asking them of course.

Comment: In iOS 10.3.1, when you tap the info button for the phone listing in the recent calls list, the most recently used number for the contact will have the word "recent" next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in Phone App. Goto "Recent" tab, tap the "i"(information) icon, you can see more detail of this contact, please note the telephone number marked as blue, this is the DN called you.

Comment: should be highlighted in blue as not to confuse OP. also, FYI, this is the same for emails and MMS, anything highlighted in blue is the point of contact of the sender

Comment: Hey nelson, did they removed this feature with iOS 9?

Comment: In iOS 9, in the outgoing calls there is a phone highlighted, but in the incoming calls there isn't any phone highlighted.